# Que signifie l'expression "Geste de transparence" ?

Tags: expressions

J'ai cherché un peu partout mais je n'ai rien trouvé. Je pense savoir la signification dans un contexte mais je ne suis pas sur.

> **De ce geste de transparence**, venant anticiper les potentielles interrogations des quelque 810 000 futurs bacheliers et étudiants, on ne retient toutefois pas grand-chose

Comment: Transparency here could be unbiasedness or clearness, a sort of objectivity in pedagogy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un *geste de transparence*, c'est ici une marque de bonne volonté qui consiste à rendre publiques des informations auparavant confidentielles, et plus précisément ici une partie du code source de Parcoursup, logiciel gérant les affectations des bacheliers dans l'enseignement supérieur.

The meaning of *geste* is the one used by the idiom *[faire un geste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/geste)*

> *Faire un geste.* Donner un gage de sa bonne volonté sans s'engager réellement pour autant. *Lui, c'est un amateur, il y est entré parce qu'il trouvait ça bien, pour faire un geste. Nous, on ne pouvait pas faire autrement* (Sartre, *Mains sales*, 1948, 3etabl., 3, p. 99). *Faire (avoir) un geste (généreux)*. En matière d'assistance, apporter une contribution modeste à défaut d'une plus importante. *Monsieur Alessandrovici, vous avez eu un geste généreux. C'est très beau, c'est très chic, très noble* (Aymé, *Tête autres*, 1952, p. 236).

The meaning of *[transparence](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/transparence)* is that one:

> Qualité d'une institution qui informe complètement sur son fonctionnement, ses pratiques. *Au niveau de l'entreprise de presse, l'esprit a été de concevoir, dès 1936, une réglementation par laquelle serait obtenue la « transparence » (connaître le véritable responsable et les véritables ressources), condition de la loyauté* (Belorgey, *Gouvern. et admin. Fr.*, 1967, p. 144).

Ref: TLFi.